# Getting undefined when iterating from JSON API results

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems reading my JSON result from an API.

My data looks like this:

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Company1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Company2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm reading it like this:

```
$.get(API_URL + '/dashboard/', function (data) {
    var newHTML = '';

    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        newHTML +=  data[i].Name;
    });

    $('#dashboard').html(newHTML);

});
```

data[i] is returning undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question: does `API_URL + '/dashboard/'` actually refers to a page/module/php file? why there is no `data.php` or `data.json`?

Comment: @Mr.Web why should it be `.php` or `.json` in the url? :-S

Comment: If `data` is of the given structure, then the nested array is in the `data.Data`

Comment: API_URL + '/dashboard/' is an external site that returns an asp.net web api  json structure.  If I console.log(data) then I get (object) (object) so I know it's returning data (can also see the valid JSON being returned using a packet sniffer)

Comment: "then I get (object) (object)" --- what does it mean? If the presented structure is correct - you should iterate over `data.Data`

Comment: @zerkms if I change the code to  $.each(data.Data, function (i, val)  then data[i].Name returns undefined?

Comment: Why do you access `data[i]`? There is `val`. If you want to access by index explicitly - you must `data.Data[i]`

Comment: How do I use val ? (Ive only ever iterated by data[i])

Comment: You just use it as any other variable. `newHTML += val;` Never put anything in your code unless you understand it.

Comment: $.each(data.Data, function (i, val) {
            newHTML +=  val;
        }) gives me [object Object] for each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
$.get(API_URL + '/dashboard/', function (data) {
    var newHTML = '';

    $.each(data.Data, function (i, val) {
        newHTML +=  val.Name;
    });

    $('#dashboard').html(newHTML);

});
```

The `each` function need to parse the `data.Data`, not just `data`...

Sounds like a pun! But should work!

Comment: Why do you have `val` but not use it?

Comment: Thanks, nice concise answer

Comment: Now it's ugly. Why don't you use `val` instead?